# custom ordering to django model

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

```
class MemberAdmin(CustomUserAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    redirect_model_name = 'memberaccountproxy'
    change_form_template = 'loginas/change_form.html'
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name','country', 'gender',
                    'created_at', 'profile_pic')
    search_fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
    add_form = AccountProfileForm
    list_filter = (
        'gender', 'incomplete', 'email_verified', 'suspended',
        'deleted',
    )        
    # profile1 = None

    def get_queryset(self, objects):
        return Account.objects.filter(usertype=1)

    def country(self, obj):
        profile1 = Profile.objects.get(account=obj)
        if profile1.country:
            return profile1.country
        return ''
    country.admin_order_field = 'country'
```

What I am trying to achieve is to make my country column on Member list page sortable.(currently its not)

Problem is that I get the 'obj' from method **country** as an Account object(as defined in the get_queryset()), & later I use that obj to get another object of type Profile (which has a member variable country). But when I try to register the country method to 'admin_order_field', it can only take member variables of obj (of type Account, which doesn't have country variable in it).

Is there a way to sort the country column based on the field from Profile class instead of Account.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    account = models.OneToOneField(Account)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Country Living In', related_name='+')
    # name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey('Status', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Marital Status', related_name='+')
    btype = models.ForeignKey('Btype', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Body type', related_name='+')
    bheight = models.IntegerField(choices=HEIGHT, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Height')
    phystatus = models.ForeignKey('EthnicOrigin', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Ethnic Origin', related_name='+')
    createdby = models.ForeignKey('CreatedBy', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Profile Created By',
                                  related_name='+')
...........................


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    usertype = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=USER)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=(('Male', 'Male'), ('Female', 'Female')), max_length=10, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, verbose_name="Mobile No", null=True)


    temple = models.ManyToManyField('Account', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="MatchMaker")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    acc_for = models.ForeignKey('CreatedBy', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Profile Created For")
    country_code = models.ForeignKey('CountryCode', max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
............................................
```

Answer (score 0):

The `list_display` and `admin_order_field` option supports double underscore notation to access related models.

Your question isn't clear because you haven't shown your models, but it looks like you can do:

```
country.admin_order_field = 'profile__country'
```

However, you can probably replace `country` with `profile__country` in your `list_display` method, and remove your `country` method entirely.

Comment: I'm not sure why that isn't working for you. Hope you figure out the problem.